# Adding subplot to a program changes the way histograms are displayed

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot

I am using example code for Pyplot histograms taken from [this page](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) of the matplotlib website as a starting point to build something else.

When I want to modify it to use subplots (with the intention of using the other subplots to display other types of plot) as in the following code, the output gets all screwed up and the histogram is spread on multiple plots, even though I only reference the first element. What am I missing?

[image: Display showing the different subplots being used]

The original code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example data
mu = 100 # mean of distribution
sigma = 15 # standard deviation of distribution
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

num_bins = 50
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
# add a 'best fit' line
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--')
plt.xlabel('Smarts')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title(r'Histogram of IQ: $\mu=100$, $\sigma=15$')

# Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of ylabel
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
plt.show()
```

The modified code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, axarr = plt.subplots(3, sharex=False, sharey=False)
# example data
mu = 100 # mean of distribution
sigma = 15 # standard deviation of distribution
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
num_bins = 50
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
# add a 'best fit' line
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
axarr[0].plot(bins, y, 'r--')
axarr[0].set_title(r'Histogram of IQ: $\mu=100$, $\sigma=15$')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how subplots work. Take a look at some examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)

Here is the code to get 3 subplots doing different things. Here, I have plotted the same histogram again 3 times, but you can change this as you like.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(311) # This represents a (3x1) grid (row x col) and we are plotting the (1) subplot. The last number increments row-wise.

# example data
mu = 100 # mean of distribution
sigma = 15 # standard deviation of distribution
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
num_bins = 50

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
# add a 'best fit' line
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
ax.plot(bins, y, 'r--')
ax.set_title(r'Histogram of IQ: $\mu=100$, $\sigma=15$')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312) # Second subplot

# example data
mu = 100 # mean of distribution
sigma = 15 # standard deviation of distribution
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
num_bins = 50

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
# add a 'best fit' line
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
ax2.plot(bins, y, 'r--')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313) # And the third subplot

# example data
mu = 100 # mean of distribution
sigma = 15 # standard deviation of distribution
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
num_bins = 50

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = ax3.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
# add a 'best fit' line
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
ax3.plot(bins, y, 'r--')
plt.show()
```

[image: Histograms in different subplots]

Comment: Thanks, your example is much clearer than the documentation I was reading.

Comment: No problem, you can comment here again if you have any doubts :)